# MVC json vs. ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

new to programming.  I am trying to print a PDF from MVC, it works well if I use Action Link, here is my code:

```
  <%= Html.ActionLink("Print","GeneratePdf","Home", new { fc="Test" },null) %>

   public ActionResult GeneratePdf(string fc)
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("\n\n"));
            // need to add the user name
            iTextSharp.text.Paragraph p = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("Name: " + fc);
            p.Alignment = 1;
            document.Add(p);

            document.Close();
            byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
            SendPdfToBrowser(byteInfo);
            return null;
        }

   public void SendPdfToBrowser(byte[] buf)
        {
            string filename = "Certificate.pdf";

            // Prepare the headers.
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

            // Write the PDF data.
            Response.BinaryWrite(buf);

            // Flush the buffer to the browser.
            Response.End();
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Clear();
        }
```

I need to use Json, here is the code:

```
function PrintChart(fc) {

                 var fc = "Test";
                 var url = '<%= Url.Content("~/Home/GeneratePdf") %>';
                 $.post(url, { fc: fc },
            function (content) {
                if (content != null) { 5 }
            }, "json");

 <input type="button" onclick="PrintChart();" value="Print" />
```

I don't get any errors but it does not generate the PDF file.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: which one works json or Actionlink and when you say it does not generates pdf file you mean you do not get the file to download

Comment: ActionLink works.  Using Json does not download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Ajax to download file. The jQuery $.post() will expect the response from the server is text. 
To download file in a Ajax way, a general approach is to use a hidden iframe and set the src of the iframe to the URL of the file

```
<iframe id="hiddenFrame" src="" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;"></iframe>
```

In PrintChart() create URL including data as query-string and set the src of the iframe:

```
 function PrintChart(fc) {

    var fc = "Test";
    var url = '<%= Url.Content("~/Home/GeneratePdf") %>';
    url += "?fc="+fc;

    $('#hiddenFrame').attr('src', url);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kibria, it worked well however if I change it to var fc = $('#vtest1').val();    <input type="text" id="vtest1" name="vtest1" value="Test"/>  it does not work?

Comment: Actually it works  var fc = $("#vtest1").val();  I used duble quotations.  Thanks again